# Retrieving an action method attribute from a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, attributes

Let's say I have the three following action methods in an MVC3 controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowReport()
{
    return View("ShowReport");
}

[PageOptions(OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Web)]
public ActionResult ShowReportForWeb()
{
    return View("ShowReport");
}

[PageOptions(OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Pdf)]
public ActionResult ShowReportForPdf()
{
    return View("ShowReport");
}
```

In my Razor view, I'd like to be able to tell:

1. Whether the PageOptions attribute was attached to the calling action method.
2. If it was, what the value of its OutputFormat property is.

Here's some pseudo-code illustrating what I'm trying to do:

```
@if (pageOptions != null && pageOptions.OutputFormat == OutputFormat.Pdf)
{
@:This info should only appear in a PDF.
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The view should not have any knowledge of the controller. It is better to pass output format option to the view in a viewmodel from controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LeffeBrune is correct, you should pass that value as part of your ViewModel

Just create an enum

```
public enum OutputFormatType {
    Web
    PDF
}
```

And use this in your ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel {
    ...
    public OutputFormatType OutputFormatter { get; set; }
}
```

And then assign the value in your Controller actions

```
public ActionResult ShowReportForWeb()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel { OutputFormatter = OutputFormatType.Web };
    return View("ShowReport", model);
}

public ActionResult ShowReportForPdf()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel { OutputFormatter = OutputFormatType.PDF };
    return View("ShowReport", model);
}

public ActionResult ShowReport(MyViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Cool beans, I'll refactor my code to go this route instead.  tyvm!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to [AlfalfaStrange's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11916389/1105881) that controller's action should not know about attributes attached to it. Which means that these attributes should in fact be action filters which intercept `OnResultExecuting` and inject this data into a well-known place in `ViewData`.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm currently doing -- I was just wondering if there was a way of making it available as a strongly-typed value without using ViewData.

Comment: You can do that strong-typed, if your model is strong-typed (and you are ready to share model between controller and attribute). Model is a part of `ViewData`.